# cakephp: using a join for search results

Tags: cakephp

I've completely confused myself now.

I have three tables: `applicants`, `applicants_qualifications`, and `qualifications`.

In the index view for applicants, I have a form with a dropdown of qualifications. The results should be a list of applicants with that qualification.

So I need the table of applicants on the index view to be based on a join, right?

If I add this to my applicants_controller:

```
$options['joins'] = array(  
    array(  
        'table' => 'applicants_qualifications',  
        'alias' => 'q',  
        'type' => 'left outer', // so that I get applicants with no qualifications too   
        'conditions' => array('Applicant.id = q.applicant_id',)  
    )  
);
$this->Applicant->find('all', $options);
```

I get an additional sql statement at the bottom of the page, with the left outer join but the sql without the join is there too.

I think this line:

```
$this->set('applicants', $this->paginate());
```

calls the sql statement without the join.

Looks like I need to combine the join $options with the paginate call. Is that right?

If I use the search form, I get:  Unknown column 'Qualifications.qualification_id' in 'where clause'

So the page is obviously not yet 'using' my sql with the join.

Sorry - I'm still a noob. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set `conditions`, `joins`, etc for your model's pagination, you must do it as follows:

```
function admin_index() {
    $this->Applicant->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'Applicant' => array(
            // 'conditions' => array('Applicant.approved' => true),
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'applicants_qualifications',  
                    'alias' => 'ApplicationsQualification',  
                    'type' => 'left outer',
                    'conditions' => array('Applicant.id = ApplicationsQualification.applicant_id')  
                )
            )
            // 'order' => array('Applicant.joined DESC')
        )
    );
    $this->set('applicants', $this->paginate());
}
```

I've commented out some sample keys that you can include later on - just to give you an idea of how it works.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks once again RabidFire! works perfectly.
I'm loving cakephp and stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join instead of left outer join.For eg.

in cource controller

```
$cond =   array(
            array(
                'table' => 'colleges',
                'alias' => 'Colleges',
                'type' => 'inner',

                'conditions'=> array('Colleges.college_id = Courses.college_id')
            )

            ) ;


        $courses = $this->Courses->find('all',  
            array('joins' =>$cond,'conditions' => array("Courses.status ='1' AND Colleges.status='1' "),
                    'order'=>array('course_name'),
                    'fields' => array('course_id','course_name'),'group'=>'Courses.course_id'
                )
          );
```