# CakePHP : complexe paginated query does not sort on columns

Tags: cakephp, join, pagination

I want to use a complexe query with `paginate()`. Here is my code :

```
// PhasesController.php
public function manage($id = null) {
    $this->loadModel('ProjectDomainPhasesUser');
    $this->ProjectDomainPhasesUser->recursive = 0;
    $this->paginate = array(
      'ProjectDomainPhasesUser' => array(
      'order' => array('Phase.label_'.$_SESSION['lang']),
      'joins' => array(
         array(
            'table' => 'users',
            'alias' => 'User',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectDomainPhasesUser.user_id = User.id AND User.id = '.$this->Auth->User('id')
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'project_domains_phases',
            'alias' => 'ProjectDomainsPhase',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectDomainsPhase.id = ProjectDomainPhasesUser.project_domain_phase_id'
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'processes_phases',
            'alias' => 'ProcessesPhase',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectDomainsPhase.process_phase_id = ProcessesPhase.id'
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'phases',
            'alias' => 'Phase',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProcessesPhase.phase_id = Phase.id'
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'projects_domains',
            'alias' => 'ProjectsDomain',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectDomainsPhase.project_domain_id = ProjectsDomain.id'
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'domains',
            'alias' => 'Domain',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectsDomain.domain_id = Domain.id'
            )
         ),
         array(
            'table' => 'projects',
            'alias' => 'Project',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array(
             'ProjectsDomain.project_id = Project.id'
            )
         )
      ),
      'fields' => array('Project.title', 'Project.date_target', 'ProcessesPhase.step_number', 'Domain.label_fr AS domain_fr', 'Domain.label_es AS domain_es', 'Phase.label_fr AS phase_fr', 'Phase.label_es AS phase_es', 'ProjectDomainsPhase.date_notification', 'ProjectDomainsPhase.done', 'ProjectDomainsPhase.date_finished', 'ProjectDomainsPhase.id')
      )
    );
    $this->set('taches', $this->paginate());
```

I made this by following [cakephp: using a join for search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566324/cakephp-using-a-join-for-search-results/4568179#4568179)

My view :

```
// manage.ctp
<table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Project.title','Projet'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Project.date_target','Date cible du projet'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ProcessesPhase.step_number','Etape'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Domain.domain_'.$_SESSION['lang'],'Domaine'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Phase.phase_'.$_SESSION['lang'],'Tâche'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ProjectDomainsPhase.date_notification','Date notification'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo __('Statut'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('ProjectDomainsPhase.date_finished','Date fin tâche'); ?></th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($taches as $key => $tache){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $tache['Project']['title']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Date->date_inv($tache['Project']['date_target']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $tache['ProcessesPhase']['step_number']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $tache['Domain']['domain_'.$_SESSION['lang']]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $tache['Phase']['phase_'.$_SESSION['lang']]; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Date->date_inv($tache['ProjectDomainsPhase']['date_notification']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php 
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="data['.$key.'][ProjectDomainsPhase][done]" value=0 />';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="data['.$key.'][ProjectDomainsPhase][done]" value="1"';
    if ($tache['ProjectDomainsPhase']['done']==1)
    echo ' checked';
    echo ' />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="data['.$key.'][ProjectDomainsPhase][id]" value='.$tache['ProjectDomainsPhase']['id'].' />';
    ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo $this->Date->date_inv($tache['ProjectDomainsPhase']['date_finished']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php };
?>
</table>
```

My problem is that in my view, all the data are great but when i try to sort, by clicking a column, the page reload but nothing change.

Comment: Do you have sortable data?

Comment: I don't know what it means. Maybe the problem could come from here...

Comment: Well do you have enough different records so that when you sort on some field the data  representation would change?

Comment: Yes I have, and the values are different so i could sort them if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a new solution for this..

Actually i too faced the same problem and finally got a trick to do this..

Here is my join query and functionality..

```
        $fields = array('SubjectCategory.name,Subject.name');
        $joins = array();
        $joins[] = array(
            'table' => 'subject_category_link',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('SubjectCategoryLink.subject_id = Subject.subject_id'
            ),
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'alias' => 'SubjectCategoryLink',
        );
        $joins[] = array(
            'table' => 'subject_category',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => 'SubjectCategory.subject_category_id = SubjectCategoryLink.subject_category_id',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'alias' => 'SubjectCategory',
        );
        $conditions = array('SubjectCategory.parent_category_id' => NULL);
        $limit = 10;
        $group = 'Subject.name';
        $this->paginate = array('Subject' => compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'joins', 'group'));
        $order='';
       /* Here you should solution code provided bellow */

        $this->paginate('Subject');
```

The cakephp paginator component only sort the above records when i call the bellow code in my view file..

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('Subject.name');
```

The problem i faced i cant able to sort the records by SubjectCategory.name by clicking the link generated in view file.

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('SubjectCategory.name');
```

But it works only at initial load by defining $order in controller..

```
$order = 'SubjectCategory.name asc';
```

So i analyzed the paginator component (located in app/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php) in cakephp and got a trick to sort the records..

1.Add this part before your paginate call ($this->paginate('Subject')) in controller..

```
    if (array_key_exists('sort', $this->params['named'])) {
        $order = $this->params['named']['sort'] . ' ' . $this->params['named']['direction'];
    } else {
        $order = 'Subject.name asc';
    }
    $this->Session->write('paginate_custom',1);
    $this->paginate = array('Subject' => compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'joins', 'group'));

    $this->set(compact('order'));// Dont forget to set this order variable to view
```

1. Go and edit the cakephp paginator component.(app/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php)

At line 141 you can see the bellow code in paginate() function.

```
 $options = $this->mergeOptions($object->alias);
```

After this line you add the bellow logic.

```
    if ($this->Controller->Session->read('paginate_custom')) {
        unset($options['sort']);
        unset($options['direction']);
        $this->Controller->Session->delete('paginate_custom');
    }
```

3.In your view replace the bellow code at each sort call ($this->Paginator->sort('SubjectCategory.name') )

```
    <td><?php
         $col_string = explode(' ', $order);
         $col = $col_string[0];
         if ($col == 'SubjectCategory.name') {
             $dir = ($col_string[1] == 'asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
         } else {
             $dir = 'asc';
         }
         echo $this->Paginator->sort('SubjectCategory.name', 'Name', array('direction' => $dir));?>
    </td>
```

I think this may help you..

All the best..

Happy programming..